# php regex for multiple terms

Tags: php, regex

I have this string (comes from the GoDaddy listing xml) and I wish to assign each of the values to a variable:

Auction Type: Offer, Auction End Time: 08/12/2012 05:57 AM (PDT), Price: $4,000, Number of Bids: 0, Domain Age: 0, Description: 1234 I declare a thumb war, 1234ideclareathumbwar.com, Traffic: 0, Valuation: $0, IsAdult: true

My question is, how do I do so using regexp?

I've tried this out:

```
$re  = "Auction Type: (.+?), ";
$re .= "Auction End Time: (.+?) \(.+?\), ";
$re .= "Price: .(.+?), ";
$re .= "Number of Bids: (.+?), ";
$re .= "Domain Age: (.+?), ";
$re .= "Description: (.*?), ";
$re .= "Traffic: (\d*)(.*?)";
$re .= "Valuation: (.+?), ";
$re .= "IsAdult: (.+?), ";

if(preg_match("~".$re."~is",$description,$m)){
    $record = Array('auctiontype' => trim($m[1]),
        'endtime'     => strtotime($m[2]),
        'price'       => str2float($m[3]),
        'bids'        => trim($m[4]),
        'age'         => trim($m[5]),
        'description' => addslashes(trim($m[6])),
        'traffic'     => trim($m[7]),
        'valuation'   => trim($m[8]),
        'isadult'     => trim($m[9])
    );
}
```

but it does not work. May I ask for assistance?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you printed result array after match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leon Kramer said, you have to change the last element of your re to:

```
$re .= "IsAdult: (.+)$";
```

and, also, the line `$re .= "Traffic: (\d*)(.*?), ";` holds 2 groups (i.e. $m[7] and $m[8]), so change

```
$record = Array('auctiontype' => trim($m[1]),
    'endtime'     => strtotime($m[2]),
    'price'       => str2float($m[3]),
    'bids'        => trim($m[4]),
    'age'         => trim($m[5]),
    'description' => addslashes(trim($m[6])),
    'traffic'     => trim($m[7]),
    'valuation'   => trim($m[8]),
    'isadult'     => trim($m[9])
);
```

to

```
$record = Array('auctiontype' => trim($m[1]),
    'endtime'     => strtotime($m[2]),
    'price'       => str2float($m[3]),
    'bids'        => trim($m[4]),
    'age'         => trim($m[5]),
    'description' => addslashes(trim($m[6])),
    'traffic'     => trim($m[7]),
    'valuation'   => trim($m[9]),   // here
    'isadult'     => trim($m[10])   // and here
);
```

I don't know what you want to do with `$m[8]` that is empty in the given example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$re  = "Auction Type: (.+?), ";
$re .= "Auction End Time: (.+?) \(.+?\), ";
$re .= "Price: .(.+?), ";
$re .= "Number of Bids: (.+?), ";
$re .= "Domain Age: (.+?), ";
$re .= "Description: (.*?), ";
$re .= "Traffic: (\d*)(.*?), ";
$re .= "Valuation: (.+?), ";
$re .= "IsAdult: (.+?)$";
```

you forgot one `,` also I changed `,` to `$` for the last part of $re

Comment: Whoa! There it is! Thanks a lot! :D